# What is the word for set containing other sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

For example, define $S = \{\{3\}, \{2,1\}, \{1,1,1\}\}$. What is the word for $S$?

Multiset? Doesn't seem to be correct.

Edit:   Also, how can I denote the cardinality of a specific set within a set?

Comment: There is no special name for this but just set would be accurate enough. But a good name would be a collection of sets in order to avoid "set of sets".

Comment: Also, how can I denote the cardinality of a specific set within a set?

Comment: Just a nonempty set.

Comment: The cardinality is just the number of elements, $S$ has three elements so $|S| = 3$. The cardinality of the elements themselfs are $|\{3\}|=1$, $|\{2,1\}| = 2$ and $|\{1,1,1\}|=3$.

Comment: @Winther: Normally $|\{1,1,1\}|=1\neq3$. But one may assume that OP meant a multiset here, which should be written differently to avoid confusion.

Comment: A set of sets is often called a *family* of sets. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_of_sets

Comment: I have the same question - in my case I have set D is fully contained in set C, which in turn is fully contained (or subset) of B, which again, is a subset of A. How would one describe these sets? I've used the word 'cumulative', but this is not quite correct.
I dont know how to put in mathematical notation here to simplify my statement above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your $S$ is a set. Sets don't really much care what they contain - they're still sets. Really, a set is just an object $S$ which we interrogate about its members - we have this "membership relation" of $x\in S$ which is true if $x$ "contains" $S$ and false otherwise - and $x$ could be anything, including other sets.

It looks like you have the set of [partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of three here, if we're being very specific. Really, you ought to represent that as a set of *multisets* (since $\{1,1,1\}=\{1\}$ as sets). The distinct here is that a multiset $M$ not only tells you if $x\in M$, but how many of $x$ are in $M$ - so it gives a bit more information than a set (but again, it doesn't matter *what* it contains, so much as *how* it contains it).

(As to your edit, you would, for a $s\in S$, describe its cardinality as $|s|$ - it's no different from how one usually describes cardinality - you just make sure to apply it to the element rather than the whole set)

Comment: I think you made a typo, should be "if $S$ "contains" $x$"?

Comment: I don't think it is the best idea to define partitions of $n$ as _being_ multisets, even though they correspond bijectively to finite multisets of positive integers of size$~n$. (This makes defining the Young diagram of a partition somewhat more difficult than necessary.) But defining "$2+1+1$" to be a partition of $4$ as does WP is certainly worse. IMHO the best definition is a weakly decreasing sequence $(\lambda_i)_{i\in\Bbb N}$ of nonnegative integers with (finite) sum $n$.

Answer (score 4):

In ZF, every element of a set is itself a set, but we typically do not think about sets this way, e.g. $\mathbb R$. However, if a set is presented like your example, we typically call it a "set of sets", a "collection of sets", or simply a "set".

Answer (score 1):

As written the question is confusing, since $\{1,1,1\}=\{1\}$ according to the usual conventions of set theory. One may assume that you meant the inner sets to be multisets instead, in which this equality is not true, and $\{1,1,1\}$ would be considered to have three (identical) elements, or more properly one element (namely $1$) with multiplicity$~3$. In that case your $S$ is a *set of multisets*.

Unfortunately there is no standard convention for multisets written by explicit enumerations of their elements. Personally I have written $\{\!\!\{1,1,1\}\!\!\}$ with double braces to signal the different interpretation (but with close spacing to distinguish from $\{\{1,1,1\}\}$ which is a singleton set containing a (in this case singleton) set, more naturally written as $\{\{1\}\}$. So you would have $$S=\{\{\!\!\{3\}\!\!\},\{\!\!\{2,1\}\!\!\},\{\!\!\{1,1,1\}\!\!\}\}$$
For the size (sum of element multiplicities) of a multiset$~M$ you could write $|M|$ or $\#M$ according to what is your conventions for ordinary sets; once it is made clear that $M$ is a multiset there should be no confusion. In the example the elements $s\in S$ have $|s|=1,2,3$, respectively.

Another notation you might sometimes need is for the multiplicity of a given element$~x$ as element of a multiset$~M$. I would suggest something like $\mu_x(M)$ so that $\mu_1(\{\!\!\{1,1,1\}\!\!\})=3$. Similarly you might sometimes need a notation for the underlying set of $M$ (an ordinary set obtained by forgetting nonzero multiplicities), for which one might suggest something like $\overline M$, but I really don't think there is much agreement about what is a good notation for this.